# Are there any reasons to use Hashtables when there is a generic Dictionary class?

Tags: .net, generics, dictionary, hashtable

Are there any reasons to use Hashtables when there is a generic Dictionary class? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you're using .NET 1.1 or the micro-framework, no. Ditto the other pre-generics collections, with the *slight* exception of some of the classes in [`System.Collections.Specialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.aspx) namespace, which don't all have direct generic replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not anymore unless maybe you're working with, or need to interoperate with, .NET 1.x code.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is fast becouse it knows about what to store. But If you want to store objects then HashTable is faster becouse element of HashTable are object types.